# How do i stop a dynamic sidebar inside an asp listview from collapsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

the animation works btw, whenever i click a menu, the submenu will automatically dropdown. the problem now is every time i click an item on the submenu it collapses as it filters the data table.

heres my code:

```
  <div id="contentWrapper">

                    <ul id="leftNavigation">

                        <li><a href="#"><i class="leftNavIcon"></i>Hardware</a>
                            <asp:ListView ID="lvHardware" runat="server">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <ul>
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                                    </ul>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSidebar" runat="server" CssClass="submenuLink" OnClick="lbSidebar_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TableKey")+";"+Eval("TableValue")%>'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right leftNavIcon"></i><%#Eval("TableValue")%></asp:LinkButton>
                                       </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
       </div>
```

the repeaterAssets is another repeater for my Table. im using the dynamic linkbuttons to filter the content of my table

codebehind:

```
    protected void lbSidebar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Business.Assets asset = new Business.Assets();
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        string[] arg = new string[2];
        arg = btn.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
        int yourValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(arg[0]);
        string breacrumbValue= arg[1];
        phBreadcrumb.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<li>"+breacrumbValue+"</li>"});
        repeaterAssets.DataSource = asset.FilterGridview(yourValue);
        repeaterAssets.DataBind();
    }
```

and here is what the DOM explorer is showing me:

```
<ul>
<li>

<a class="submenuLink" id="MainContent_lvHardware_lbSidebar_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lvHardware$ctrl0$lbSidebar','')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right leftNavIcon"></i>Desktop CPU</a>

</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is `lbSidebar_Click` defined and what does it look like? The problem will most likely be in that JS/jQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after playing around the code, i finally fixed it. the code in not the prettiest but it did the trick for me.

```
                <ul id="leftNavigation">

                    <li id="liHardware" runat="server"><a href="#"><i class="leftNavIcon"></i>Hardware</a>
                        <asp:ListView ID="lvHardware" runat="server">
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <ul>
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                                </ul>
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSidebar" runat="server" CssClass="submenuLink" OnClick="lbSidebar_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TableKey")+";"+Eval("TableValue")%>'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right leftNavIcon"></i><%#Eval("TableValue")%></asp:LinkButton>
                                   </li>
                                </ul>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
   </div>
```

code behind:

```
protected void lbSidebar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Business.Assets asset = new Business.Assets();
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string[] arg = new string[2];
    arg = btn.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
    int yourValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(arg[0]);
    string breacrumbValue= arg[1];
    phBreadcrumb.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<li>"+breacrumbValue+"</li>"});
    repeaterAssets.DataSource = asset.FilterGridview(yourValue);
    repeaterAssets.DataBind();
    liHardware.Attributes.Add("class","active");
}
```

i just added a class that will display:block the li wrapper when the linkbutton is clicked.

```
.active{display:block;}
```